Handling Unpredictable MediaError AUDIO_RENDERER_ERROR with HTML Audio Element
When attempting to play the audio using the HTML audio element, it sometimes fails to play, resulting in a MediaError with the message 'AUDIO_RENDERER_ERROR' and error code 3. When trying to play multiple times, the audio starts to play randomly.
Steps to reproduce the problem

Initialize an audio context.
Fetch the list of MP3 audio files.
Decode MP3 files to obtain audio buffers.
Combine decoded audio buffers into a single buffer.
Convert the combined buffer into WAV format.
Generate a blob from the WAV audio data.
Create a URL for the joined audio data.

Observations:

The issue is being reproduced specifically in android devices.
The issue does not occur in Firefox, Safari, issue occurs specifically in Chromium based browsers (Chrome, Edge).


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
